# how to hightlight words in anycase ( uppercase, lowercase partially or fully )?

Tags: java, android, regex

I have EditText to search `searchKeyword` inside paragraph(paragraph are inside SQLite database).

```
String Contentstr = paragraph.replaceAll(searchKeyword,"<font color=\"red\">" + searchKeyword + "</font>");
txtV.setText(Html.fromHtml(Contentstr));
```

above code hightlights like this:

When I searched "Hi hi" (searchKeyword="`Hi hi`"),database search function return anycase letters ( i mean, "`hI hi`" or "`HI HI`" or and so on ), it hightligts "`Hi hi`" but replace all others "`hI HI`", "`hI hi`",.. etc into searchKeyword="`Hi hi`". 
I don't want to replace like that.
 When I search "`Hi hi`", it must hightlight "`Hi hi`" and others "`hI hi`" or "`HI HI`" without replaceing others into "`Hi hi`".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make your regex case insensitive add `(?i)` at start of it. Also you can use matched part in replacement using `$index` where `index` is index of matched [group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

So using these informations you can try something like

```
String Contentstr = paragraph.replaceAll("(?i)"+searchKeyword, 
                       "<font color=\"red\">$0</font>");
```

---

Also in case your `searchKeyword` contains some [special characters](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html#special) wrap it with `Pattern.quote()` to produce regex that will automatically escape special meaning of these characters

```
String Contentstr = paragraph.replaceAll("(?i)"+Pattern.quote(searchKeyword), 
                       "<font color=\"red\">$0</font>");
```

Comment: what is $0? What does it exactly mean?

Comment: @DentalBoom `$0` represents string that was found by your regex. 0 is index of [group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) 0 which represents entire match.

Comment: Thanks you very much.sir...... i can't vote up bcoz i have low reputation sorry about that... ^_^